# Does google scholar rescan papers and update citations?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, indexing

I have an *in press* paper (let's call it paper A) which is cited in another *in press* paper (paper B). The citation is complete (issue nr. etc.). The citing paper (B) was supposed to be published after the cited one (A), but it appears that one publisher is much faster, so B will be out before.

Does anyone know if Google Scholar citations will miss this citation? Or will it re-scan paper B and at some point add a citation to paper A?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Article metadata and bibliography management is usually a service provided by the journal. In this there might be variations in the diligence with which it is done. But in general the metadata and citations data are pushed to indexing services. So yes, Google Scholar does get the updated data, either directly or via crawling, and will update citations, page and volume numbers after publications, etc.